# How are WAV Channel Data values scaled?

Tags: node.js, audio, wav

For a project I am decoding wav files and am using the values in the data channel. I am using the node package "node-wav". From what I understand the values should be in the thousands, but I am seeing values that are scaled between -1 and 1. If I want the actual values do I need to multiply the scaled value by some number?

Part of the reason I am asking is that I still do not fully understand how WAV files store the necessary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't exactly know how node.js is but usually audio data is stored in float values so it makes sense to see it scaled between -1 and 1.

What I pulled from the website:

> **Data format**
>
> Data is always returned as Float32Arrays. While reading and writing 64-bit float WAV files is supported, data is truncated to 32-bit floats.

And endianness if you need it for some reason:

> **Endianness**
>
> This module assumes a little endian CPU, which is true for pretty much every processor these days (in particular Intel and ARM).

If you needed it to scale from float to fixed point integer, you'd multiply the value by the number of bits. For example, if you're trying to convert to 16 bit integers; `y = (2^15 - 1) * x`, where `x` is the data value, `y` is the scaled value.